# split a string list in one cell to row with python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this table:

| product | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Prdct_1Prdct_2Prdct_3Prdct_4Prdct_5Prdct_6 | 23.7.2022 | 100 |

and the result should be

| product | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Prdct_1 | 23.7.2022 | 100 |
| Prdct_2 | 23.7.2022 | 100 |
| Prdct_3 | 23.7.2022 | 100 |
| Prdct_4 | 23.7.2022 | 100 |
| Prdct_5 | 23.7.2022 | 100 |
| Prdct_6 | 23.7.2022 | 100 |

How should I solve it with python?

Comment: split and `explode()`?

Comment: explode doesn't work in this case, since as I read the excel table in jupyternotebook, the product column looks like this Prdct_1\nPrdct_2\nPrdct_3\nPrdct_4\nPrdct_5\nPrdct_6.

Comment: For the same of the question, can you confirm whether your `Prdct_1Prdct_2Prdct_3Prdct_4Prdct_5Prdct_6` are literals? How does it generalize with real data?

Comment: If you have `\n`, then split on `\n`. Please provide the output of `df.head().to_dict('list')` for reproducibility. Also please try `df.assign(product=df['product'].str.split('\n')).explode('product')`

Comment: OK, then it's a duplicate, I'll close the question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), the subtlety is how to determine the splitting points?

Assuming you want to split after the digits, use the `(?<=\d)(?=\D)` regex (split after a digit and before a non-digit):

```
out = (df.assign(product=df['product'].str.split(r'(?<=\d)(?=\D)'))
         .explode('product')
      )
```

Output:

```
   product       date  value
0  Prdct_1  23.7.2022    100
0  Prdct_2  23.7.2022    100
0  Prdct_3  23.7.2022    100
0  Prdct_4  23.7.2022    100
0  Prdct_5  23.7.2022    100
0  Prdct_6  23.7.2022    100
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4DLN7l/1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try splitting and exploding. For example,

```
data = {
    'product': ['Prdct_1Prdct_2Prdct_3Prdct_4Prdct_5Prdct_6'],
    'date': ['23.7.2022'],
    'value': [100]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['product'] = df['product'].str.split('Prdct_')
df = df.explode('product')
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

product date    value
0       23.7.2022   100
1   1   23.7.2022   100
2   2   23.7.2022   100
3   3   23.7.2022   100
4   4   23.7.2022   100
5   5   23.7.2022   100
6   6   23.7.2022   100
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
headers = ["product", "date", "value"]
row_values = ["Prdct_1Prdct_2Prdct_3Prdct_4Prdct_5Prdct_6" , "23.7.2022", "100"]

delimiter
split_values = row_values[0].split("_")

table_dict = dict(zip(headers, [split_values] + row_values[1:]))

print(table_dict)
```